# .htaccess rewrite directories with index.html to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

At the site were some directories with html files like:

```
site.com/folderone/index.html
site.com/foldertwo/index.html
```

and it was available by links like:

```
site.com/folderone
site.com/foldertwo
```

now all these directories moved to /old-pages:

```
site.com/old-pages/folderone/index.html
site.com/old-pages/foldertwo/index.html
```

but old links should be available, so .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folde(.*)$ /old-pages/folde$1 [L]
```

it's rewrite correct *site.com/folderone/* and *site.com/folderone/index.html*

the problem is: for **site.com/folderone** it's not rewrite but redirect to **site.com/old-pages/folderone/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect is probably happening because of mod_dir and the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive, which redirects requests for a directory that is missing the trailing slash so that the trailing slash is there. There's a **good** reason why that happens, as there's a info disclosure security concern without the trailing slash.

What you can do to avoid the redirect is either turn it off (not recommended):

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

or include the slash via mod_rewrite so that the two modules won't interfere with each other over the same request:

```
RewriteRule ^folder([^/]+)$ /folder$1/ [L,R=301]
```

You must add that before your other rewrite rules so that it gets applied first. Then your other rule should work.